# Why my add a review/be the first one to review is not showing in product/view.phtml page in magento?

Tags: magento, review

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I have used the bellow code in the default theme then its showing but in my theme its not... can't find out why ?

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                        <?php echo count($detailedInfoGroup); ?>
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                      <?php endforeach;?>
                    <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span>

                        <?php echo $html ?>



        <?php endif; ?>
```

for the above code the last one that is reviews is showing...but not in my theme.
Its working fine on base theme ('default') .... but when my theme is activated  Its showing fatal error on the same link.

Comment: Your 2nd code block is out of foreach loop. please check

Comment: I know I have done this for getting the last element that is 'review' in the array...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin section then under catalog => Review and rating => Manage ratings

Then select store id for every record then it will show on your product page.